# Modulo Arithmetic Shortcut

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider two numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $0<x<y<7500$.  Consider a function $m(x,y)$, defined: $m(x,y)= (2019201913*x + 2019201949*y ) \bmod 2019201997$.

May this function be simplified?

Define $m(x,y) = (ax+by)/c$. I noticed that a, b, and c are equal to 8 orders of magnitude ($20192019 \_ \_$) .

Comment: $2019201913\equiv-84\bmod2019201997$ and $2019201949\equiv-48\bmod2019201997$

Comment: Thus $m'(x,y) = 2019201997-(84*x + 48*y)$?... Obviously, this breaks down after a certain domain, specifically for values of $(x,y)$ for which $m'(x,y)<0$.  However, for this specific problem, $0<x<7500$ and $0<y<7500$, so $m'$ will never be less than $0$.  All correct?

Comment: You still have to do modular reduction, but it’s simpler to multiply by $84$ than to multiply by $2019201913$

Comment: Okay. Given that $0<x<y<7500$, would I still have to perform modular reduction?

Comment: You're correct in that domain

Comment: $m(x,y)\equiv -12(7x+4y)\pmod{\!2019201997}.\ $ "Simpler" depends on what you plan to do with it.

Comment: for once @BillDubuque we agree.

Comment: 2019201949 has a factor of 7 just like -84 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that:

- $2019201913 ≡ -84 \pmod{2019201997}$
- $2019201949 ≡ -48 \pmod{2019201997}$

$m(x,y)$ may be simplified to $m(x,y)= (-84x-48y) \bmod 2019201997 $. Given that $x,y \in (0,7500) $, $m(x,y)$ can be considered to be equal to $2019201997-84x-48y$.  This, of course, may be further simplified to $2019201997−12(7+4)$.